# How to reduce permits in semaphore Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have this following function that reduces the number of shopping carts available to use in a supermarket

```
    public boolean removeCart(){
        if(carts > k.initialCarts){
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                carts-=1;
                return true;
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This code would acquire a permit and never release it.

What I want to achieve is this following situation:

There are 2 carts available, so 2 clients are inside the supermarket. However, there is a line of other 10 people waiting for the carts in order to go inside the supermarket. I want to reduce the number of carts once one of the 2 clients inside gets out of the supermarket.

That means, I want my function's 'acquire' to skip the queue of all the other's, so it takes one permit and never releases it.

How am I able to achieve this?

Comment: let one of people owing a cart do not release permit, that's it.

Comment: Your explanation is kinda difficult to understand. Could you rephrase it please? Why do you *reduce* the amount of cards when one gets out? Shouldn't it be *increased* so the waiting persons can take it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reduce the original number of permits from semaphore pocket you need to:

1. Create your own semaphore class by extending the Semaphore super class.
2. Override the reducePermits() method, which is protected in the super class, and make it public as follows:

```java
    public class mySemaphore extends Semaphore {

    // Constructor for your subclass

    public mySemaphore(int permits){
          super(permits);
    }

    //override super class' method
    public void reducePermits(int reduction){
        super.reducePermits(reduction);
      }
    }
```

- Now, rewrite your code using your own semaphore class and you can reduce the original number of permits from your semaphore