# Java Semaphore reducePermits vs acquireUninterruptibly without release

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237076/how-to-reduce-permits-in-semaphore-java), why is there a need for the reducePermits() method? Can't I use acquireUninterruptibly and never do a release?

I came across this because I'm trying to reduce the number of permits in Striped semaphores where [implementing reducePermits isn't feasible](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html#lazyWeakSemaphore(int,%20int)).

Comment: From the documentation: `This method differs from acquire in that it does not block waiting for permits to become available.`

Comment: P. S. "striped" being a regular ol' adjective should be lower case.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like `acquireUninterruptibly` joins the queue whereas I can think of `reducePermits` as jumping to the front of the queue because it doesn't do any interrupts.